# How to deal in safari ios devices with css writing-mode?

Tags: php, html, css, safari, responsive-design

I have a css class of `vertical-text` wherein this .vertical-text will make a text to be in vertical position. Everything is okay, but when I tried on my iphone, safari. It is not working. I don't know if safari browser issues or more on ios issues?

Here's the vertical-text class:

```
.vertical-text {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
    -webkit-writing-mode: tb-lr;
    -moz-writing-mode: tb-lr;
    writing-mode: tb-lr;

    -ms-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    -moz-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;

    -ms-writing-mode: sideways-lr;
    -webkit-writing-mode: sideways-lr;
    -moz-writing-mode: sideways-lr;
    writing-mode: sideways-lr;
}
```

Here's my sample html:

```
<td class="{{ $step['color'] }}-pure w-10-p text-white" rowspan="4">
    <label class="vertical-text text-center font-weight-bold">STEP {{ $step['id']}}</label>
</td>
```

Here's the sample output in PC (google chrome)

[image]

Comment: Up up up pleaseeee

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply additional CSS not just on writing-mode but on transform also to satisfy different render engines.

I used scale instead of rotate, but got the same result.

```
.vertical-text {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -ms-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    transform: scale(-1, -1);
    text-orientation: mixed;
}
```

I tested it with Safari 16.1. And it gave me a working solution.

**Minor note:**

During work I realized that in Safari if you put the CSS on the `<td class="vertical-text">` element's class it won't work. You need to put a child element inside the `<td>` with the class just like in the question. Other browser will display it vertically if you put the class on `<td>` without error.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're still needing an answer, I just figured out if you use transform on the inner contents of a table cell, the cell dimensions do not calculate properly in Safari iOS. Once I removed transform, the writing-mode worked fine. The outcome is your step labels will face outward instead of inward but at least the table doesn't blow up.